# hide/show popup on ajax request using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a submit using ajax but I'm facing issues, I'm having two popup one is #popup-subscribe and the other is #popup-subscribe-success, I wanted to hide the first popup on subscribe and show the second popup.

This is how I open the first popup:

```
<button class="btn btn-round btn-primary mt-1 w-100" data-toggle="popup" data-target="#popup-subscribe">Subscribe Now</button>
```

The first popup is:

```
<!--  Subscribe PopUp  -->
<div id="popup-subscribe" class="popup col-10 col-md-4 p-6" data-animation="slide-up">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="popup" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <form action="#" method="post" name="form-subscribe" id="form-subscribe">
    <h5>Stay Updated</h5>
    <p>Latest news direct to your inbox — <mark>no spams</mark>.</p>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Your Full Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email_id" placeholder="Your Email Address">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cell_no" placeholder="Your Cell Number">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and the second popup is:

```
<!--  Subscribe Success  -->
<div id="popup-subscribe-success" class="popup col-10 col-md-4 p-6" data-animation="slide-up">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="popup" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <h5>Stay Updated</h5>
  <p id="subscriber_ip"></p>
  <p>Latest news direct to your inbox — <mark>no spams</mark>.</p>
</div>
```

and the script I'm using is:

```
  //form-subscription-submit-action
  $("#form-subscribe").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "assets/php/ajax_functions.php",
      data: $(this).serialize()+"&action=form-subscribe",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
        if(data.status==1) {
          $("#popup-subscribe").hide();
          //$("#popup-subscribe-success").find("#subscriber_ip").html(data.subscriber_ip)        
          $("#popup-subscribe-success").show();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

the first popup is getting hidden but the second popup is not getting visible.

Comment: Do you have any CSS defines for `#popup-subscribe-success` ? It may have something like `display: none !important;` which is forcibly overriding what `.show()` tries to do. However this looks like `popup` ... may be part of some other js library, like a modal box? That may have some of its own events and handlers which could also be conflicting (like its position is 'off the screen').

Comment: Have you tried using `$( '#popup-subscribe-success' ).attr( 'style', 'display:block !important' );`? Also, what does the console say?

Comment: Please add to your question: how you show the first popup to start with (it may shed light on how to show the second one on ajax success).

Comment: @GrantMiller tried using $( '#popup-subscribe-success' ).attr( 'style', 'display:block !important' ); and console says nothing

Comment: @IncredibleHatI have updated my question with the button code to open the popup, the id's don't have any CSS definitions